# Different Colored text in <option>

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to color the * in this option red using CSS?

```
<option value="0">Please Make a Selection&nbsp;*</option>
```

Comment: not in this manner. Also styling options is not working in all browsers (like IE)

Comment: This is typically handled by having an asterisk next to the select box as opposed to next to the first value option.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Changing the colour of a dropdown list when closed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274813/changing-the-colour-of-a-dropdown-list-when-closed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this.  Leave the first `option` blank and `position` some text over top of it.

```
<select name="" id="">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="" class="bar">Option 1</option>
</select>

<div id="makeSelection">Please Make a Selection <span>*</span></div>
```

CSS

```
select{
    width:200px;
}

div#makeSelection{
    position:absolute;
    top:14px;
    left:15px;
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:13px;
}

div#makeSelection span{
    color:red;
}
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/TqpMS/

Of course, you would probably need to fiddle with the styles. And you may need to wrap it in a `div` with a `position:relative;` depending on how you page is set up.

Comment: Definitely an option, will have to ask.

Answer (score 0):

It's important to note that the [`option` element's content model](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/the-button-element.html#the-option-element) doesn't support sub-elements, as it's just supposed to contain "text". What this means is that you'll actually have very little control over the styles if you keep your html valid.

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AmpMb/) of a number of things I've tried that flat-out haven't worked. Pardon the `<font>` element; I figured if writing invalid markup was ok that it just might work in this case (fortunately it didn't).

Answer (score 0):

To add to the other answers, if you do require a red asterix on the first element, consider having it as a background image on the option element.

Answer (score 0):

No it is not.
The only thing you can style is the option tag and you can't/shouldn't nest any elements inside of option.

There are a few work-arounds that you can do.

- Create a background image for the asterisk (*) and style around that.
- use a list instead of select or datalist.

If I recall, there is a js plug in that will replace select with ul and replace option with li. from there you can nest a element to wrap the asterisk and style it from there. Than again, you could always just write your own.

Comment: We are using the msdropdown which give us that capability, however, unsure how to do it.

Comment: Nice. If that is the case then you should be able to just flat out style that.

msdropdown changes select and option to div,span, and A.
If you look at the output after it does it's magic, you will notice that there are now ID's and Classes you can use to target what you want.